Entra ID App Registration no Roles in Token object with elytron-oicde-client
We have the problem that with Microsoft Entra ID in conjunction with an app registration and the JBoss Elytron OIDC client, the roles are not available in JBoss.
We were able to identify the problem. It is related to the scope. An app registration requires the specification of the API scope so that the roles are included in the access token. The scope cannot be passed with the Elytron OIDC client. Does anyone know another solution in conjunction with JBoss EAP 7.4 to obtain the roles using the Elytron OIDC client?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
